# Ansible Just Hangs

Tags: ansible

I had everything for the most part working the way I wanted.  And then, I have not clue how this happened;  none of my Ansible playbooks will connect to remote systems (It Just Hangs).  I can SSH into them fine from command line, with any account.
Below is a Ansible Ping test.  My localhost is fine, and playbooks will execute.  but, not with my remote systems.
I've gone as far as removing all accounts, creating new keys, and reinstalling Ansible

ansible.cfg, is currently at default settings (which is nothing enabled),  and I have cleared everything in ~/.ansible

```
**Remote System** 

[root@SELC01 ~]# ansible -vvv servers -m ping -u root --ask-pass -K
Using /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file
SSH password: 
SUDO password[defaults to SSH password]: 
META: ran handlers
Using module file /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/modules/system /ping.py
<10.6.16.106> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: root
<10.6.16.106> SSH: EXEC sshpass -d12 ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o User=root -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/roo/.ansible/cp/13665ce0cd 10.6.16.106 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'echo ~ && sleep 0'"'"''


**LocalHost**

[root@SELC01 ~]# ansible -vvv localhost -m ping -u root --ask-pass -K
Using /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file
SSH password: 
SUDO password[defaults to SSH password]: 
META: ran handlers
Using module file /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/modules/system/ping.py
<127.0.0.1> ESTABLISH LOCAL CONNECTION FOR USER: root
<127.0.0.1> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'echo ~ && sleep 0'
<127.0.0.1> EXEC /bin/sh -c '( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1496147239.75-82726750768823 `" && echo ansible-tmp-1496147239.75-82726750768823="` echo /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1496147239.75-82726750768823 `" ) && sleep 0'
<127.0.0.1> PUT /tmp/tmpklwEPM TO /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1496147239.75-82726750768823/ping.py
<127.0.0.1> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'chmod u+x /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1496147239.75-82726750768823/ /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1496147239.75-82726750768823/ping.py && sleep 0'
<127.0.0.1> EXEC /bin/sh -c '/usr/bin/python2 /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1496147239.75-82726750768823/ping.py; rm -rf "/root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1496147239.75-82726750768823/" > /dev/null 2>&1 && sleep 0'
localhost | SUCCESS => {
    "changed": false, 
    "invocation": {
    "module_args": {
        "data": null
    }
```

thank you for your help.

Comment: Does this happen on all hosts? I occasionally also had the problem but only on one host. A reboot of this host helped, but I have no clue to what's the problem or how to reproduce this behaviour.

Comment: You seems to be running ansible from 'root' user and in your previous question you was running it as 'ansible' user.

Comment: `-o ControlPath=/roo/.ansible` is that a typo for `root` ?

Comment: @SethosII - its with all Hosts,  I've rebooted all systems,  no change....

Comment: @AlexD - correct,  I was using ansible, but starting over,  using root for now, most of my config is fairly basic. Just trying to keep it simple, while learning Ansible....

Comment: @thrig  - /roo/.. is a cut-n-paste TypeO

Comment: 'root' and 'ansible' users have different environment and use different ssh keys. Also remote login as user 'root' is frequently disabled and if you have something like 'fail2ban' installed then you get yourself banned from accessing remote servers after failed authorisation.

Comment: @AlexD - my RHEL systems are plain vanilla hosts.  yea, root and ansible (user)  did have completely different keys.  But, I started over, and Ansible user has been removed.   I can create users, keys, etc. and SSH into the remote systems,  but not with using any Ansible Playbook, etc..   Just Hangs .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed it, known_hosts had an issue. I remove the 10.6.16.106, ssh-keygen -R 10.6.16.106 and , ran ansible ping, it added it back in , and it worked.

Answer (score 3):

The reason for me for a similar case was that a command was running that had popped up a user prompt (in this case `pam-auth-update` was prompting about "do you want to overwrite local changes?" and ansible just appeared to hang with no output.

This was the last message I saw:

```
<myhost.mydomain.com> SSH: EXEC sshpass -d11 ssh -vvv -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o 'User="ansible-workstations"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/home/myuser/.ansible/cp/613727008e -tt myhost.mydomain.com '/bin/sh -c '"'"'sudo -H -S  -p "[sudo via ansible, key=bxoslxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxcecomzhwgo] password:" -u root /bin/sh -c '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'echo BECOME-SUCCESS-bxoslxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxcecomzhwgo ; /usr/bin/python3 /home/ansible-workstations/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1653360662.635262-17538-210907314970534/AnsiballZ_command.py'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"' && sleep 0'"'"''
Escalation succeeded
```

Then absolutely nothing, indefinitely until I pressed CTRL+C.
Eventually I went and ran the command manually on the target host and discovered the prompt. I then added `--force` to the command and all was good.

Comment: Same for me, I used `ssh` with `pexpect` to connect to a non-*nix machine. As it was my first connection attempt, I was prompted to accept a self-signed certificate. But of course, the prompt was not shown in Ansible.